# Hibernate criteria to use distinct date values on the basis of day only

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using Hibernate Criteria API and using projection for my result shown below:

```
projList.add(Projections.property("router"), "router");
projList.add(Projections.property("date"), "date");

criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
```

Output:

```
2017-01-10 19:47:33.0   Router1
2017-01-11 20:45:59.0   Router1
2017-01-10 21:58:49.0   Router2
2017-01-10 21:59:00.0   Router2
```

This code works as expected but i want to run distinct function on the basis of unique date records, meaning distinct function should not consider time value but just the day value. So out put should be like:

```
2017-01-10  Router1
2017-01-11  Router1
2017-01-10  Router2
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for doing it:

Instead of

```
projList.add(Projections.property("date"), "date");
```

Use

```
projList.add(Projections.sqlProjection( "date(date) as date", new String[] {"date"}, new Type[] {StandardBasicTypes.STRING} ));
```

Where expression "date(date) as date" first "date" is mysql Function, "(date)" is HBM column name of date, as "as date" is return column name from mysql and type "date" will be bean name that will be populated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, though not so clean..

**a)** Create a POJO class in which the projections results will be stored

```
public class Proj{

   private Date date;
   private String router;

   // .. getters / setters
}
```

**b)** Use an 'sqlProjections' for the date property in your criteria API (native sql here .. im on MySql):

```
projList.add(Projections.sqlProjection("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date", new String[]{"date"},new Type[] {new StringType()}));
```

This is enough to get the distinct values you are seeking though the date will be in a String format, if you want to transform it to date then:

**c)** Add a ResultTransformer to the criteria api:

```
.setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {
      public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
         java.util.Date parsed = null;
         try {
              parsed = format.parse((String) tuple[1]);
         } catch (ParseException e) {}

         Proj p = new Proj();
         p.setDate(parsed);
         p.setRouter((String)tuple[0]);
         return p;  
      }
)
```

Like i said this is not the prettiest solution but it worked for me.
The criteria call now returns an objects which encapsulated the results you seek.

Comment: StringType is asbtract and can not be initialized